# How to set batch size in train_on_batch for a convolutional neural network in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to online-train a neural network. I want to use the Tensorflow Keras train_on_batch function on a convolutional neural network. Here it is:

```
look_back=1600
inputTensor = keras.layers.Input([look_back+3,2])
inputTensorReshaped = tf.reshape(inputTensor, [1, look_back + 3, 2, 1])
#split into 2 groups
inputgroup1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :3], output_shape=((1, 3, 2, 1)))(inputTensorReshaped)
inputgroup2 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 3:look_back + 3], output_shape=((1, look_back,2, 1)))(inputTensorReshaped)

conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=(10, 2), activation='relu')(inputgroup2)#10
pool1 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv1)
dropout1 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pool1)
norm1 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(dropout1)

conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(8, 1), activation='relu')(norm1)
pool2 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv2)
dropout2 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pool2)
norm2 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(dropout2)

conv3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(6, 1), activation='relu')(norm2)
pool3 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv3)
dropout3 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pool3)
norm3 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(dropout3)

conv4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(4, 1), activation='relu')(norm3)
pool4 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv4)
dropout4 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pool4)
norm4 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(dropout4)

conv5 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation='relu')(norm4)
pool5 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv5)
dropout5 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pool5)
norm5 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(dropout5)
flatten1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(norm5)
dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(flatten1)

misclayer1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputgroup1)
miscdropout1 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(misclayer1)
miscnorm1 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(miscdropout1)

misclayer2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(miscnorm1)
miscdropout2 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(misclayer2)
miscnorm2 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(miscdropout2)

misclayer3 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(miscnorm2)
miscdropout3 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(misclayer3)
miscnorm3 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(miscdropout3)
miscflatten1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(miscnorm3)
misclayer4 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(miscflatten1)

rejoinlayer = keras.layers.Concatenate()([dense1, misclayer4])

processing1 = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(rejoinlayer)
totalnorm1 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(processing1)
processing2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(totalnorm1)
totaldropout1 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(processing2)
processing3 = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(totaldropout1)
totalnorm2 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(processing3)
processing4 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(totalnorm2)
totaldropout2 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(processing4)
processing5 = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(totaldropout2)

output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(processing5)

model = keras.Model(inputTensor,output)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.00005, momentum=0.1, nesterov=True), loss="mean_squared_error")

#trains the model with the 1st state, action, and value
def train():
    global qtable
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(0, 8):
        state = qtable.loc[qtable.index[i], "state"]
        action = [qtable.loc[qtable.index[i], "action"], qtable.loc[qtable.index[0], "action"]]
        x.append([action])
        x[i].extend(state)
        y.append([qtable.loc[qtable.index[i], "value"]])

    print("training...loss:")
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        print(model.train_on_batch(np.nan_to_num(np.array(x)), np.nan_to_num(np.array(y))))
```

In this case the variable "state" would be a 1202-by-2 list [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...] and the variable "action" would be a 1-by-2 list [a,b] before being appended/extended to x. In theory, the training I want is a batch size of 8 with a 1203-by-2 input shape. However, I get this error:
*ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 19248 elements to shape [1,1203,2,1] (2406 elements) for '{{node model/tf.reshape/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](IteratorGetNext, model/tf.reshape/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [8,1203,2], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,1203,2,1].*

This shows that all the inputs and outputs are being put into the CNN at once which is not what I want. Instead, I want the data to be in a batch of 8. How can I do this??? Am I even using "train_on_batch" correctly

Comment: keras.Model(inputTensor,output, epoch=3, batch_size=8);  --Epoch: an epoch is all training samples trained once.  --batch_ Size: calculate the sample size of each batch during gradient descent